# Selecting elements of a vector conditional on their names, replacing all others with zero

Tags: r

Suppose

```
a <- c(10 : 17)
names(a) <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8")
a <- as.data.frame(a)
```

which gives the vector (or a [1 , 1:8] matrix)

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

I would like to select elements based on their column names and replace every other element to zero.

For example, choosing "a2" and "a4" would give

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 
 0 11  0 13  0  0  0  0
```

One solution would be to select each element and set to zero `a[1] = 0`, `a[3] = 0`, ... but is very inefficient and time consuming.

I've also tried `a <- replace(a, a[ , grepl("a2", colnames(a))] , 0)`, but this removes the column names and does nothing with the elements.

Which code can do this efficiently, without using loops?

Comment: Are you dealing with a named vector or data.frame or matrix?

Comment: A named vector containing only numeric values. The names of my real object have three letters plus a number like (aaa1, aaa2 ... )

Comment: Then you should make your example data using `a <- setNames(10:17, paste0("a", 1:8))` or similar

Comment: Thank you, that's much more efficient. I checked my real object and it's a data.frame which I convert into a numeric vector using a <- as.numeric(a). WOuld the code also work with a data.frame?

Comment: Any reason you're using `colnames(a)` for the vector and not `names(a)`?

Comment: I transposed it, but I can remove that and edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the named vector/matrix
Using `colnames()` instead of `names()` for a single 'row' - although I would use `names()` if it is just a named vector.

Let's say you want to select 'a2' and 'a4' only.

```
sel <- c("a2", "a4")

a[,!colnames(a) %in% sel] <- 0
a
```

This works because we are selecting columns - from a matrix with 1 row.
We can use the column names to subset columns.

```
> a
     a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8
[1,]  0 11  0 13  0  0  0  0
```